# Config OpenVPN on Window Server 2008 R2 for client can connect server's Lan network

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, openvpn, route

I installed openvpn 2.1 on my Windows Server 2008 R2.
My server has 2 network adapter.

The first adapter connect to internet. (default gateway here)

The second adapter connect to lan network. ip 10.11.11.243 subnet mask 255.255.255.128

Here is my server config:

```
port 1234
proto udp
dev tun
ca "ca.crt"
cert "server.crt"
key "server.key"  
dh "dh1024.pem"
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.11.11.0 255.255.255.0"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

My server start properly, it got vpn ip: 10.8.0.1

My client connect through internet IP of server and connected and has ip 10.8.0.10

But i cant connect with orther computer in server lan network. Cant connect to any 10.11.11.x ip.

How can i config server for my client can connect to 10.11.11.x server lan network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to enable routing between both interfaces.

To do so :

Open the Windows registry and navigate to :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
```

Then set the following registry value:

```
Value Name: IPEnableRouter
Value type: REG_DWORD
Value Data: 1
```